# I can't run a .sh file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh

Every time I run the command

```
./test.sh
```

it returns with

```
bash: ./test.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How can I get rid of the "ctrl + m" at the end? I use notepad++ to edit the file if that helps.

Comment: `dos2unix ./test.sh` should solve your issue otherwise you might need to manually add the `^M` and remove it using an editor. A temporary work around could be `tr '\r' '\n' < ./test.sh | bash` but there are no guarantees...

Comment: can u try rewriting the script using vi or vim ?

Comment: Did you write this file on windows? Does every line end with `^M`?

Comment: `notepad++` is crystal clear that the script was made in Windoes...

Comment: I made it on windows and doing "vi" does not show the "^M"

Comment: Yes, it was written in vi, but edited using `notepad++`